# EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY does not set the video quality

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am working on android automation and trying to set video quality by adb command. I am using follwing command:

```
  adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE  --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1 --ei android.intent.extras.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY 1   -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity
```

But it does not seem to set the quality. Any ideas?

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a little correction here:

Instead of using EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY 1, we can do VideoQuality

so our command would be :

```
 adb shell am start -a android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE  --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1 --ei android.intent.extras.VideoQuality 1   -n com.android.gallery3d/com.android.camera.CameraActivity
```

Comment: Thanks You :).  i had to dig into source code but finally found it :)

Comment: Change "--ei android.intent.extras.VideoQuality 1" to
"--ei android.intent.extra.videoQuality 1"

Comment: @dudeck; Changed the answer to reflect your comments. Thank you :)